# Can a view in Cloudant be filtered on parameters that weren't part of it's key

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I want to be able to search emitted docs from a view, on fields that weren't part of it's generation but rather fields that are added by way of linked documents.

[As explained in the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents)

If these were my records: 

    `[
    { "_id": "11111" , "name": "pandora" },
    { "_id": "22222", "ancestors": ["11111"], "value": "hello" },
    { "_id": "33333", "ancestors": ["22222","11111"], "value": "world" }
    ]`

and the view was this:

```
    function(doc) {
    if (doc.value) {
    emit([doc.value, 0], null);
    if (doc.ancestors) {
      for (var i in doc.ancestors) {
        emit([doc.value, Number(i)+1], {_id: doc.ancestors[i]});
      }
    }
```

Would it be possible to search the returned docs by sorting on 'name' ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not search linked documents. They are linked to the couchdb document that was emitted. `include_docs` parameter just fetches the document corresponding to the _id for you. The view is sorted on the key and can only be filtered by the emitted key.

When a couchdb view is built sorting is done on the key that is emitted from the view. In your case the documents will be sorted on `value` and you can filter the results only by using `key=some-value`. However you can emit a complex json key like `{value:doc.value,name:doc.name}` and query on both name and value.

Unrelated to your question but cloudant has a couch-db lucene that can be used to cover all sorts of complex querying scenarios.

Comment: Hi Akshat, thanks! I did try to find out if Lucene could be used to query a view but couldn't find anything that said I could.

Comment: Lucene does not query a view. You have to build seperate indexes for lucene  The [readme](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) has good info on the kind of stuff you can do with it. Instead of linking the document you could try denormalizing them and storing it with the parent itself so you can built your views in a way that you can filter the entire document. Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: The issue with denormalizing in this particular case is that, 'name' is constantly updated, like every 15 secs, while 'value' culd be updated every one hour or so. Putting all data into one document means updating the whole document every 15 secs.
And thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do what you suggest in a two view approach.

**View 1 - Lookup the name to get the document _id**

All you need to do here is to emit documents with a name. In the emit function you would emit the name as the key and the doc._id as the value. The output would look like this:

```
   key: "pandora", value: [11111]
```

You may need to reduce this if you have more than one id with the same name.

**View 2 - Create the output you require per document _id**

The second view is more complex. You could emit for each document with a value and store the 'position' by using an array with empty values. this could look like this:

```
    id 22222: key: 11111, value: ["hello"]
    id 33333: key: 22222, value: ["world"] 
    id 33333: key: 11111, value: ["","world"]
```

Assuming that there will always be at most one defined/non-empty entry per key and array position, your reduce function could reduce this to:

```
    key: 11111, value: ["hello","world"]
    key: 22222, value: ["world"]
```

**Performance Concerns**

You mentioned that the names update once per 15 seconds. Your documents look small so around 6k updates per day does not appear an issue to me. However, you should consider the following:

- A view index is updated whenever you request it, not when the documents are updated.
- Your views should first and foremost check if they can dismiss the document. You can dismiss documents with "name" in view 2 and documents with "value" in view 1.
- I am not sure how often you'll access the view but you can use the **key** parameter on both views so you immediately get the document you want.
- You can consider using stale views (this means that the view will be reindexed **after** returning the last set of results) so some very few responses may be out of date the first time you query the view after an update.

Comment: would this mean that every time the name is changed(15 secs), it could trigger a change in the indexes for the view?

Comment: No. Couchdb will update a reindex every time a view contained in the design document is requested. So if say you need to get the values of linked documents once per hour, then around 240 documents would be updated (That's assuming you only update on document every 15 seconds.)

Comment: I see. Thanks @DHK. If I have understood right ie. putting your suggestion in perspective of the problem, I would need three views.

The first view that indexes on the 'value' as the primary search is on the 'value'. Second view, that emits 'name' instead of 'doc_id' and the third view that emits every time the first view is accessed.
 
If I am still on track, are there any performance implications I should be aware of?

Comment: 2 views, performance implications should not affect you much on a change of name every 15 seconds (unless all names change).

Comment: Hi @DHK. I need to first query on 'value' - this 'value' changes every one hour- and then for the documents returned for 'value', I need to do a second search on 'name' ('names changes every 15 secs. and yes, all names might change. and the above I added as an example just to explain the problem. The actual documents are huge.)

Comment: This might be tricky, but it really depends on too many factors for me to help you out. I guess you'll have to try.

Comment: I'll note that you tagged the question with #cloudant. On Cloudant, the views are built automatically / continuously, avoiding the delay at query time.